# Updating an imageview's image in a NIB

Tags: ios, ios5, uiimageview, imageview

I have created multiple imageViews within one custom cell. How do I target to update a specific image view within the NIB?

I have given it a restoration ID, can I access it using this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use the tagging for that...to distinguish one view from another

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html

find the tag method here

Comment: I can set a tag on the image view in the NIB, but how do i reference this image in code to then set the new image.

Comment: do you have an example of your code? I'm curious how you setting the images to the views...are they included into your project as a bundle or they just located on your machine somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Setting up the imageview as an outlet so i could then reference it worked